Confused about filename extensions in the Save pane
When using a text editor, like TextEdit or Smultron, and saving a new file, the standard save-as pane appears and asks for a name. The text in question is source code in BASIC, so I will type something like "example.bas". When the text is saved, the extension disappears from the, view.
If I go into the Finder and edit the name there, I do not see the extension. If I add it, it appears.
It's all a bit confusing, does anyone know exactly what it's doing with the extensions I type in?

There is a setting to show/hide file extensions. I’m not at my Mac, so here is a link explaining:
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/show-or-hide-filename-extensions-on-mac-mchlp2304/mac

Looking in get info, the files have no extension when I save them.

If you have hide extensions enabled it will look like your files have no extensions.
